# Error compiling freertos for nucleo stm32f767

Tags: cmake, stm32, freertos, cubemx

I have generated code using cubeMX and while compiling it gives me the following errors. I have already tried several fixes but none of them is working.

```
    /tmp/ccvxTV8U.s: Assembler messages:
    /tmp/ccvxTV8U.s:758: Error: selected processor does not support `vstmdbeq r0!,{s16-s31}' in Thumb mode
    /tmp/ccvxTV8U.s:760: Error: instruction not allowed in IT block -- `stmdb r0!,{r4-r11,r14}'
    /tmp/ccvxTV8U.s:782: Error: selected processor does not support `vldmiaeq r0!,{s16-s31}' in Thumb mode
    /tmp/ccvxTV8U.s:784: Error: instruction not allowed in IT block -- `msr psp,r0'
```

CMakeLists.txt

IDE: CLion 2019.3

```
#THIS FILE IS AUTO GENERATED FROM THE TEMPLATE! DO NOT CHANGE!
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

# specify cross compilers and tools
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS 1)
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER arm-none-eabi-gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_WORKS 1)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER arm-none-eabi-g++)
set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER  arm-none-eabi-gcc)
set(CMAKE_AR arm-none-eabi-ar)
set(CMAKE_OBJCOPY arm-none-eabi-objcopy)
set(CMAKE_OBJDUMP arm-none-eabi-objdump)
set(SIZE arm-none-eabi-size)

SET(LINKER_SCRIPT ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/STM32F767ZITx_FLASH.ld)

#Uncomment for hardware floating point
SET(FPU_FLAGS "-mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16")
add_definitions(-DARM_MATH_CM4 -DARM_MATH_MATRIX_CHECK -DARM_MATH_ROUNDING -D__FPU_PRESENT=1)

#Uncomment for software floating point
#SET(FPU_FLAGS "-mfloat-abi=soft")

SET(COMMON_FLAGS
    "-mcpu=cortex-m7 ${FPU_FLAGS} -mthumb -mthumb-interwork -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections \
    -g -fno-common -fmessage-length=0 -specs=nosys.specs -specs=nano.specs")

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_INIT "${COMMON_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_INIT "${COMMON_FLAGS} -std=gnu99")
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_INIT "-Wl,-gc-sections,--print-memory-usage -T ${LINKER_SCRIPT}")

PROJECT(freertos_test C CXX ASM)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

#add_definitions(-DARM_MATH_CM4 -DARM_MATH_MATRIX_CHECK -DARM_MATH_ROUNDING -D__FPU_PRESENT=1)
add_definitions(-D__weak=__attribute__\(\(weak\)\) -D__packed=__attribute__\(\(__packed__\)\) -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F767xx)

file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES "Middlewares/*.*" "startup/*.*" "Drivers/*.*" "Core/*.*")

include_directories(Core/Inc Drivers/STM32F7xx_HAL_Driver/Inc Drivers/STM32F7xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F7xx/Include Drivers/CMSIS/Include Middlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/include Middlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/CMSIS_RTOS Middlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/portable/GCC/ARM_CM7/r0p1)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}.elf ${SOURCES} ${LINKER_SCRIPT})

set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS
    "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -Wl,-Map=${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}.map")

set(HEX_FILE ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}.hex)
set(BIN_FILE ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}.bin)

add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}.elf POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJCOPY} -Oihex $<TARGET_FILE:${PROJECT_NAME}.elf> ${HEX_FILE}
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJCOPY} -Obinary $<TARGET_FILE:${PROJECT_NAME}.elf> ${BIN_FILE}
        COMMENT "Building ${HEX_FILE}
Building ${BIN_FILE}")
```

I'm using the NUCLEO-F767ZI with a STM32F767

Comment: have you tried compiling it using: [STcubeide](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubeide.html), [keil](https://www.keil.com/demo/eval/arm.htm) or [Atollic® TrueSTUDIO](https://atollic.com/truestudio/)? Seems to me that your mcu configuration is wrong.

Comment: You should check where ccvxTV8U.s comes from (it is from freertos? are you sure?). Probably it shouldn't be compiled. Compiler flags seems right. (-mcpu=cortex-m7  -mthumb)

Comment: Re-run cmake with `CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=TRUE` and re-run `make VERBOSE=1` and show the compilation commands including compiler options.

Answer (score 1):

```
 file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES "Middlewares/*.*"
```

You are compiling FreeRTOS [for all possible implementations for all possible cpus](https://github.com/kylemanna/freertos/tree/master/FreeRTOS/Source/portable), so you are also compiling sources not compatible at all with your current cpu. You should compile sources only for your destination cpu.

That would most probably be, assuming the folder `Middlewares` is taken from cubemx:

```
 file(GLOB src1
      Middlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/portable/GCC/ARM_CM4F/*.c
      Middlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/*.c
 )
```

And add only the needed include path:

```
 target_include_directories(YOUR_TARGET PUBLIC
      Middlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/include
 )
```

Comment: Everything indicates that the error was in clion at compile time, when I run compile via terminal, compile correctly with the active flags.thanks for your help.